# How do I prove this Euler-Mascheroni limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

There is a number called the Euler-Mascheroni constant that is defined as the limiting difference between the harmonic series and the natural logarithm. In other words:
$$
\gamma =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\,\,\left[-\ln\left(N\right) +
\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}\right]
$$
On desmos, I shifted $\ln$ by a number $a$ and it still converges to $\gamma$. This means that, for all numbers $a$:
$$
\gamma = \lim_{N \to \infty}\,\,\left[-\ln\left(N + a\right) +
\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}\right]
$$
How do I prove that this is true $?$. I think it has to do with the concavity of the logarithm but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: There is nothing tο prove Kamal. This is the definition of $\gamma$!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left(-\ln(N+a) + \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k}\right) \\
&= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} (\ln(N) - \ln(N+a)) + \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left(-\ln(N) + \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k}\right) \\
&= \gamma + \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \ln\left(\frac{N}{N+a}\right) \\
&= \gamma + \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \ln\left(1-\frac{a}{N+a}\right),  \hspace{1em}\text{ since } \frac{N}{N+a} = \frac{N+a-a}{N+a}\\
&= \gamma + \ln(1), \hspace{8em}\text{ since ln is continuous and } \frac{1}{N+a} \rightarrow 0\\
&= \gamma
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: $\displaystyle +1$. Fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with another proof. We could make a shift for the original definition: $$\gamma=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(H_{n+a}-\ln(n+a))=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(H_n-\ln(n+a)-\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+a}\frac1k\right)$$Assuming $a$ is finite, each term in the sum goes to zero and the claim is proved.